# Is it correct to say "There will always be a better command of one language than the other"?

Tags: grammar

Suppose we are talking about bilingual people who claim they're both languages native speakers and we know exactly what those languages are, so I say "There will always be a better command of one language than the other"

Should it be "over the other", is my first example still understandable?, how weird is it for your native ears?

In the first example I think "the other" refers to the "command" rather than "the other language"  I am talking about.

Comment: An individual [or person or speaker] will always **have** better command of one language than another one. You can also say "over".

Comment: Do you want your sentence corrected, or do you want to know a natural way to make this statement?

Answer (score 4):

Three possibilities:

An individual [or person or speaker] will always **have** better command of one language.

OR ... **have better command of one language over another.**

OR ... have better command over one language than another.

[Please note: command of or over a language would not generally be described as: there is always etc. but rather ascribed to a person or persons. Also, one **can say**: a better command in those examples.]

Comment: Suppose we know exactly what those two languages are, so could I change "another" for "other"

Comment: No, you can’t. Here *another* is acting like a pronoun, and in the version “…over the other” *other* is an adjective that modifies the (elided) noun *language*. But as to your question, unlike *another*, *other* cannot serve as a pronoun, so you need *the*. Compare that with, “Yum! That is tasty. May I have another?” or “There are three chairs around the table; another is against the wall.” In that last sentence (and with a somewhat different meaning) you could end it instead as, “the other is **against the** wall.”

Comment: Oops, should have emphasized **the other** rather than **against the**. Dunno what I was thinking.

Comment: Then, it is correct to say "than the other one right?

Comment: @Quique Of course, if you have already said there is another one.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence is correct, perfectly understandable, and natural. You could include the preposition, although doing so is optional:

> There will always be a better command of one language than **of** the other.

However, using the preposition "over" would make the prepositions non-parallel, and that is often considered poor style:

> There will always be a better command **of** one language than **over** the other.

It is generally considered better style in English to maintain consistency (parallelism).

Comment: What about "There will always be a better command of one language over the other"

Comment: I would avoid that. If you assume that "than" would go between "language" and "over", then you have the same problem of inconsistent prepositions. If you assume that "than" would go somewhere else, then the objects of comparison are unclear. (The command of one language is better than what?) Either way, there's a problem.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't understand your explanation

Comment: @Quique Perhaps I can understand why you're confused by asking you a question. We use a comparative (such as "better") in order to compare two things. In your sentence, the first thing being compared is the "command of one language". What is it being compared to?

Comment: Now I get it, it is being compared to "the command of the other language the bilingual person speaks"

Comment: @Quique Yes, that seems like the most likely situation. In that case, "than" should be placed after the word "language" to make the comparison clear.

Comment: Actually I never thought of writing "There will always be a better command of one language THAN OVER the other"  As that combination seems very unlikely, I was actually asking if it were possible to use "OVER" instead of "THAN".

Comment: @Quique Generally, no, in English we don't replace "than" with "over". You might hear it in informal contexts, and the meaning would probably be clear to the listener, but in standard English that shouldn't occur, and in many situations it would sound very unnatural.